# Ant: don't print build.xml indentation with echo or fail

Tags: ant

Say I have the following in my `build.xml` file:

```
<target name="FOO">
    <echo>a
          b
          c
          d</echo>
</target>
```

The result is:

```
 [echo] a
 [echo]               b
 [echo]               c
 [echo]               d
```

I want the output to be:

```
 [echo] a
 [echo] b
 [echo] c
 [echo] d
```

To get that, I could change `build.xml` to:

```
<target name="FOO">
    <echo>a
b
c
d</echo>
</target>
```

But is there anything **else** I can do to get the same output?  Anything that keeps the `build.xml` indentation the same as the original, that is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the solution is to use line.separator property

```
<property name="nl" value="${line.separator}"/>

<target name="FOO">
    <echo>a${nl}b${nl}c${nl}d</echo>
</target>
```

Output:

```
FOO:
     [echo] a
     [echo] b
     [echo] c
     [echo] d
```

Second solution is to create custom ANT task, that will provide output as you need (your custom java code will modify ant output massage). See http://www.developer.com/java/article.php/3630721/Introduction-to-Custom-Ant-Tasks.htm